# conda: linking cython package to dll

Tags: cython, conda

I am trying to package the `ffvideo` module for conda. It is a Cython module that links into ffmpeg. I am able to build the recipe (so the linking works at compile time), however I cannot install the resulting package in a new environment. The reason is that at execution time the package cannot find the dlls it was linked to at compile time (their path is now different, because they are in a different environment).

I tried using the `binary_has_prefix_files` flag in the conda recipe, which I point to `Lib\site-packages\ffvideo.pyd`. However, it does not seem to help.

Is there a way to link Cython packages to relative paths or something like that?

The recipe is at the moment:

```
package:
name: ffvideo
version: 0.0.13

source:
fn: b45143f755ac.zip
url: https://bitbucket.org/groakat/ffvideo/get/b45143f755ac.zip
#  md5: cf42c695fab68116af2c8ef816fca0d9

build:                   [win]
number: 3              [win]
binary_has_prefix_files:
    - Lib\site-packages\ffvideo.pyd

requirements:
build:
    - python
    - cython             [win]
    - mingw                              [win]
    - ffmpeg-dev         [win]  
    - mingw
    - pywin32
    - setuptools
    - libpython

run:
    - python
    - ffmpeg-dev         [win]
    - cython
    - mingw
    - pywin32
    - setuptools
    - libpython


about:
home: https://bitbucket.org/groakat/ffvideo/
license: Standard PIL license
```

The package is on binstar https://binstar.org/groakat/ffvideo/files . The dependencies are all in my channel https://binstar.org/groakat/

One more thought. As `ffvideo` depends on `ffmpeg-dev` which I also packaged, might it be that I need to use the `binary_has_prefix_files` option there as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote Travis Oliphant's answer from the [conda mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/msg/conda/p83WQvMgX90/gNbQY0ePajkJ):

> On Windows, our current recommended approach is to:
>
> ```
> 1) put the DLLS next to the executable that needs them
> 2) put the DLLS in a directory that is on your PATH environment variable.
> ```
>
> By default, Anaconda and Miniconda add two directories to the path
>   (the root directory and %ROOT% / Scripts).  You could either put the
>   dlls in that directory or add the directory the dlls are located to
>   your PATH.